# advice with copying static list

Tags: java, android, list, static

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static List<Towar> chosen_items;

......
}

public class ItemOrder implements Serializable {
    static List<Item> item_ordered;

....
}
```

And I'm trying to do something like this:

```
ItemOrder.item_ordered = new ArrayList<Item>(MainActivity.chosen_items.size());

Collections.copy(ItemOrder.item_ordered, MainActivity.chosen_items);
```

I want to copy list from `MainActivity.chosen`_items to `ItemOrder.item`_ordered and I've got error like this :

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: destination.size() < source.size(): 0 < 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new ArrayList(10).size()` will return 0. The 10 is the initialCapacity, not the size.

You could do this:

```
ItemOrder.item_ordered = new ArrayList<Item>(MainActivity.chosen_items);
```

Or this:

```
ItemOrder.item_ordered = Arrays.asList(new Item[MainActivity.chosen_items.size()]);
Collections.copy(ItemOrder.item_ordered, MainActivity.chosen_items);
```

BTW your use of static lists has a design smell.